# Your PHP memory limit is set to 64 MB but should be set to 128M - but only for that specific script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, lamp

I try two different .sh scripts to install LAMP.

[This](https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/12/install-lamp-stack-in-ubuntu-using-shell-script.html) works without errors and when I install IPB (invision power board) it tell me that memory is ok

[image: memory ok]

But when I use [github script](https://github.com/stephenlang/bash-lamp-installer) and I install same IPB it return me a memory error

[image: memory problem]

I change from 64M to 128M value on php.ini but edit the php.ini file is useless. Is there a solution? **Is not a host problem** !

Comment: Did you restart the web server after editing the file? Also note how the setup scripts are configurable and you can set the memory limit there.

Comment: @DanielB ah... I forgot this... yes, `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a solution?

The bash variable responsible for setting the PHP memory limit to 64MB is the same across every single one of the `*_install_lamp.sh` files in that particular GitHub repository.

The simplest solution is to modify `memory_limit=64M` to `memory_limit=128M` and run the shell script again.  The reason the other script worked is because it did NOT modify the memory limit by editing php.ini upon execution.

Source: [bash-lamp-installer](https://github.com/stephenlang/bash-lamp-installer)

Comment: Yes, my problem it was not *memory_limit=64M* into *128*.. I forgot to restart Apache after installing script.. `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`